# from matplotlib import style ImportError: cannot import name 'style'

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I am receiving the following error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'style'
```

when I run

```
from matplotlib import style
```

I am using ubuntu and have tried running it with python3 and python.
I have  version (1.3.1) of matplotlib installed, which is the most up-to-date that `apt-get` installs. I have installed numpy and installed matplotlib with python3. No joy.

Has anybody else been having the same issue ?

Comment: The style module was added in matplotlib 1.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib

Did the trick. Although on my machine it initially threw up some issues. There are a number of helpful suggestions on this thread for anyone else having the issue

[ubuntu 14.04, pip cannot upgrade matplotllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674612/ubuntu-14-04-pip-cannot-upgrade-matplotllib)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use  `pip install --user --upgrade matplotlib`

Using `sudo` is deemed unsafe as you're allowing pip to execute code from the internet as root.

Using --user :

> ..makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges [Purpose of --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user)

More information on this here: [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Anaconda and IPython 3.1. You can update matplotlib to its latest version after you have installed Anaconda. Just remind that you may want to use the installer for Python 3. You will find the `style module` by using both the `matplotlib` library and `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Yeah, I was using python2, when I tried with Python3 it worked!