# How can i resolve error cannot import name style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When i run this piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
plt.show()
```

I get the following error message:

> cannot import name 'style' from 'matplotlib'

Where is the bug?

Comment: cannot import name 'style' from 'matplotlib'     This is the error i get. I installed matplotlib and import it

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763356/from-matplotlib-import-style-importerror-cannot-import-name-style

Answer (score 0):

It could be the way you installed matplotlib. In some cases `pip install matplotlib` does not work. You would try the Windows installer from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib.

If this doesn't work or it is not the case, use:

- `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

or

- `pip install --user    --upgrade matplotlib`

Make sure that the code is `from matplotlib import style`